# determine which IP addressed has been used to open a url in c#

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, networking

Say, I have 2 or more  active network cards on my machine. i am using a c# application from which i am calling an asynchronous service.
i want to be able to determine which ipaddress have i used when calling this service.

for example, my two active ip's are 192.168.10.5 and 192.168.5.7 and the service ipaddress is 192.168.7.12.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obtaining client IP address in WCF 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93162/obtaining-client-ip-address-in-wcf-3-0)

Comment: See [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93162/obtaining-client-ip-address-in-wcf-3-0)

Comment: It's slightly unclear from the question - are you trying to determine this information from the client or the service?

Comment: determine it from the client so i send it to the server, so the server can contact back the client using this address

Comment: your IPs are internal (192.x.x.x).  Is your service *also* internal?  If not, you might as well give up on this right now as there'd be no way that 192.168.10.5 would be accessible.   *Also*, it's trivial for the *server* to identify the client's IP already, so why bother passing it in?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
public static string GetExternalIP()
{
    try
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
             string ip = client.DownloadString("http://whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp");
             return ip;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception) { return null; }
}
```

Code slightly reworked from http://www.hackcommunity.com/Thread-ASKING-FOR-REP-ROCKY-PART-2

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I don't think there's a managed solution. [GetBestInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365920%28VS.85%29.aspx) and/or [GetBestRoute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365924%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) would seem to be the right places to start in the WIn32 API (probably GetBestRoute, by my reading of it).

Also, due to the vagaries of this wonderful thing that is the internet, and dynamic routing, by the time you've worked out the answer, it may have changed.

It may be best to provide the service with a list of IP addresses, and let it use whichever one works.

*Edit*

Or you may be able to use [WCF callbacks](http://dotnetaddict.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/wcf_alarmclock.htm), and make WCF do most of the hard work (I've not spent a lot of time in WCF itself, not sure how much work it would do for you here)