# wcf client service interaction

Tags: wcf

suppose i am having a wcf(mywcf),and three clients(CL1,CL2,CL3) connected to my wcf,CL1 and CL2 belongs to PC1 and CL3 belongs to PC2.                                            now the question is to dedect the client.(mywcf is having more then one endpoints).

Comment: i dont want to use any static variable

Comment: doea this help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93162/obtaining-client-ip-address-in-wcf-3-0 ?

Comment: thankx for reply but IP address for CL1 and CL2 will be same computer thus there ip will be same,i want to dedect all three clients differently on the basis of client application,

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible unless you send some identification in every message. So create custom SOAP header and `MessageInspector` and use them to transfer your client's identification.

Comment: i think client it self is a identification,there must be somthing in background by which wcf use to dedect the client.i just want to capture the that something.have u ever used .svclog generated by wcf(<system.diagnostics>) which contain the complete info of the client application

Comment: But such info is not part of communication. It is common identification of running application. If you want to pass this identification to service you must create transport mechanism for it. Service can out of the box differ clients only by their identity (users) or by IP address. If same client application connects from the same machine under same account multiple times, service is not able to differ calls.