# WCF Service Tracking Client Machine

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

In a WCF Service method (with no parameters), is it possible to work out what machine the call came from? Or would I have to pass this as a string to the method call?

Comment: What do you mean by "what machine"? Do you mean IP or computer name etc etc? You must take into account that the call may be coming from many different OSes, some which might not even have machine names

Comment: Check the following thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93162/obtaining-client-ip-address-in-wcf-3-0