# WCF: how to know if some request goes from localhost

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, localhost

Simple question:

How to know if some request/call goes from localhost in the code below?

Is it possible in fact?

Thanks!!

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
public class Service2 : IService2
{
        public void DoWork()
        {
           // Is this the localhost ?
        }
}
```

Comment: are you running on VS or wcf application host on IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find the ip address of request coming computer by using

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
```

or there are few other alternatives as well ([Obtaining client IP address in WCF 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93162/obtaining-client-ip-address-in-wcf-3-0))

based on ip address you can decide request/call goes from localhost  or not.

If you need to debug web service you can run client and service at ones and put break point on service method.