# How Get Client IP. MAC. PC name use wcf4 (tcp/ip mode)

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0, wcf-4

I have a wcf service running on LAN server, use tcp/ip mode.
Now I need to get every client info when the client send request connect the wcf service.
Because it's all on LAN. I just need get the client MAC, IP , PC name.
Is there any way to get these info ? thanks.

Comment: See [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93162/obtaining-client-ip-address-in-wcf-3-0) to find the IP. Getting a MAC and hostname from an IP are two separate questions, search and you will find.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.machinename(v=vs.110).aspx for computer name

[Get public/external IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253701/get-public-external-ip-address) for ip address

[Reliable method to get machine's MAC address in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850650/reliable-method-to-get-machines-mac-address-in-c-sharp) for MAC

Please consider googleing before posting a question, I found these answers in 2 minutes.

Comment: You foolish guy, Please read the question carefully before googling. Somebody requires client details, not server details.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var properties = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties;
var endpointProperty = properties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
if (endpointProperty != null)
{
    var ip = endpointProperty.Address;
}
```

For more information about `OperationContext` class, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).