# How to intercept a message before the token authentication phase in a wcf service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-security

I'm new to WCF. I have a client that establishes a connection to a WCF service by sending a username and password as a token. The service has a custom token authenticator which extends the `UserNameSecurityTokenAuthenticator` class to implement custom validation logic.

I want to figure out what the client IP address is from the server side and have it available in my custom token authenticator class

I've tried to add message inspectors and endpoint inspectors but these points are never hit.
I have a `customServiceCredentials` class that extends the `ServiceCredentials` class. Is this where I can intercept the message before authentication.

I know using `OperationContext` I can get the clientIp, however I just don't know where to intercept the message before it hits the token authenticator

Comment: Can you share your config code for more context.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your problem based on some of the resources I've found, but it's hard to be exactly as you described. Maybe your description doesn't describe your problem clearly. These two resources are the best in my opinion and I think they will be helpful to you.[Custom Message Interceptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-message-interceptor) [WCFInterceptors](https://github.com/mishraVivek11/WCFInterceptors)

Comment: To clarify, my goal is to get ClientIP during the wcf service authentication on failed attempts in the `UserNamePasswordValidator` class in the server. Message Interceptors don't work because the token authentication step happens during the connection establishment phase. My service has the following config: netTcpBinding with security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" message clientCredentialType="UserName" transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"

Answer (score 0):

I think the **BeforeSendRequest** method can get the **clientip** before you send the request. But after your testing, this method won't work.

This method can be tried. This method was discovered on a post that is a bit old but I thought you could give it a try.

```
OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
MessageProperties prop = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpoint = 
prop[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
string ip = endpoint.Address;
```

This is the original post:[Obtaining client IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93162/obtaining-client-ip-address-in-wcf-3-0)

Comment: Thanks! I found out the wcf context isn't instantiated during the token authentication stage of a connection. Therefore OperationContext is null and cannot be accessed. I found a way around this by adding an endpoint to report logins and get client IP from the RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.